# How do I make PHP display new lines from an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I use simplexml_load_file to open a soap envelope. When I get to one of the elements of the body, which contains plain text with new lines, and I want to display it, it's displayed without the new lines.

SOAP ENVELOPE extract:

```
[...]    
<Note>root@podio1:~# Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: clcomm: Path podio1:nge1 - podio2:nge1 being drained
Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: clcomm: Path podio1:e1000g1 - podio2:e1000g1 being drained
Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: Node podio2 (nodeid = 2) is down.
Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: Cluster members: podio1 podio3.
Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 in.routed[925]: 8056 bytes of routing message left over
Aug 10 12:18:21 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: node reconfiguration #3 completed.</Note>
[...]
```

and when I echo the note:

```
[...]
$comment = $Note->Comment;
echo $comment;
[...]
```

this is what I get on my PHP Page:

```
root@podio1:~# Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: clcomm: Path podio1:nge1 - podio2:nge1 being drained Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: clcomm: Path podio1:e1000g1 - podio2:e1000g1 being drained Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: Node podio2 (nodeid = 2) is down. Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: Cluster members: podio1 podio3. Aug 10 12:18:20 podio1 in.routed[925]: 8056 bytes of routing message left over Aug 10 12:18:21 podio1 genunix: NOTICE: CMM: node reconfiguration #3 completed.
```

Does anybody know what I can do to be able to display the new lines? 
Each line ends with [CR][LF] in the XML file.

Thanks in advance,

Cristina

Comment: haha was about to post that as answer !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3257611/46675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines have no meaning in rendered HTML.  To break to the next line you use `<br>` or `<br />` so use:

```
echo nl2br($comment);
```

Or in cases where there is no newline:

```
echo "$comment<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the content in a variable first and then run:

```
$nolines = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"),'<br>', $var);
```